# MySQL date range selection

Tags: mysql, date

Known that the following SQL statements will select a data range, which one is the most efficient one among the others, and do using `timestamp` or `datetime` will change the performance

Assume we have the table
`test` with columns `timestamp`, `datatime`
And I want to extract all records for May, 2015:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y-%m') = '2015-05'
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
WHERE timestamp >= '2015-01-01' AND timestamp <= '2015-01-31'
WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = 2015 AND MONTH(timestamp) = 5
```

Which should i avoid, and which is the best practice

Comment: Why don't you just plug them into MySQL Workbench and look at the performance for each? Sounds like you're asking someone else to do that for you.

Comment: First of all I don't know that MySQL workbench even exists, and I just wanted to know if they all work in the same way
And if you don't know if they all works the same or if they don't please let somebody else answer

Comment: @ragerory this question does not only include executing them to see which performs faster... there are more factors

Comment: Whatever happened to MySQL documentation? Saucer of milk, party of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost a subjective question because it really depends on what indexes you have on the table and columns.

if you have indexes on your column then you can use either of these two

```
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
WHERE timestamp > '2015-01-01' AND timestamp < '2015-01-31'
```

both of those can utilize the index and perform much faster

as to which of those two will execute faster, I don't think there is a difference. my preference is to use the `BETWEEN` because it makes more sense to me when reading a query. Pick one and stick with it. Consistency is key